# Remove active tabpanel with button in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, tabpanel

Hi everyone I would love to know if it's possible to remove the current active tabPanel on a shiny app :

This is my code:

```
  # server
  observeEvent(input$removeTab, priority = 20, {
     removeTab(inputId="sortTab", target=input$ACTIVE_TAB)
  })

  # ui
  actionButton("removeTab", "Remove current tab")
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. If the tabPanel that we desire to remove is encapsulated in a TabsetPanel, for example in a :

`TabsetPanel(id='sortTab',
    Tabpanel(),
    Tabpanel()
)`

We juste have to respecify the TabSetPanel id with the `input` argument on the target :

```
  # server
  observeEvent(input$removeTab, priority = 20, {
     removeTab(inputId="sortTab", target=input$sortTab)
  })

  # ui
  actionButton("removeTab", "Remove current tab")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the

`removeTab()`

function in Shiny

[remove tab example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/insertTab.html)

Comment: Yep this is what I use in my example. Unfortunately, with the removeTab example given on the link, you have to specify manually the name.